# How to know TabletPC is in 'Laptop' or 'Tablet' mode

Tags: windows, winapi, touch

I'm writing a Touch-enable application for DELL TX2, for text input, I need to know whether the TablePC is in 'Laptop' or 'Tablet' mode, then change the text input mode. In 'Latop' mode, don't call virtual keyboard, vice versa. But I didn't find any useful information from MS website and google. Is there any Windows API? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't specified the language therefore here's a link to a unit I've recently wrote http://www.delphigeist.com/2011/02/laptop-specific-functions.html check if the Lid is present, this is specific to a laptop, from what I know tablets do not have a lid, hope this helps.